# Hook to get the query result after listing posts

Tags: wp-query

As the title says, I have a filter in the listing of a custom post type page, and I must export the results, I could make that, but now I need to get the filtered results.
is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

> Hook to get the query result after listing posts

Use the [`loop_end`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/loop_end/) hook - it passes the WP_Query by reference.

```
add_action( 'loop_end', 'wpse_263822_loop_end', 10, 1 );
function wpse_263822_loop_end( $query ) {
  //* Make sure we're in the loop
  if( ! in_the_loop() ) {
    return;
  }
  //* Do something useful with the WP_Query
  print_r( $query->posts );
}
```